# Can you use drives while Raid 1 is rebuilding?

Tags: raid, software-raid, raid1

I am going to be rebuilding a raid 1 array.  While the rebuild is happening can people still read/write to data in the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use it, it'll underperform obviously and the harder you thrash it the longer the rebuild might take but by all means use it - that's kind of the point of R1 isn't it.

Comment: I'd be correct in saying RAID 5 and 6 also apply to this, yes?

Comment: Correct yes, exactly the same.